# Swift - AVAudioPlayer doesn't work properly

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I have the following code :

```
let speechRecognizer = SFSpeechRecognizer()!
let audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
var recognitionRequest = SFSpeechAudioBufferRecognitionRequest()
var recognitionTask = SFSpeechRecognitionTask()
var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    playSound(sound: "oops")
    speechRecognizer.delegate = self
    requestSpeechAuth()

}

func requestSpeechAuth(){
    SFSpeechRecognizer.requestAuthorization { (authStatus) in
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ 
            switch authStatus {
            case.authorized:
                print("authorized")
            case.denied:
                print("denied")
            case.restricted:
                print("restricted")
            case.notDetermined:
                print("not determined")
            }
        })

    }
}

// Function called when I press on my record button
func SpeechButtonDown() {
    print("Start recording")

    if audioEngine.isRunning {

        endRecording() {

    } else {
       do {

        let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord)
        try audioSession.setMode(AVAudioSessionModeMeasurement)
        try audioSession.setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)

        if let inputNode = audioEngine.inputNode {

            recognitionRequest.shouldReportPartialResults = true

            recognitionTask = speechRecognizer.recognitionTask(with: recognitionRequest, resultHandler: { (result, error) in
                print("1")
                if let result = result {
                    self.instructionLabel.text = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                    print("2")
                    if result.isFinal {
                        self.audioEngine.stop()
                        inputNode.removeTap(onBus: 0)
                        if self.instructionLabel.text != "" {
                            self.compareWordwithVoice()
                        }
                    }   
                }
            })

            let recognitionFormat = inputNode.outputFormat(forBus: 0)

            inputNode.installTap(onBus: 0, bufferSize: 1024, format: recognitionFormat, block: { (buffer, when) in
                self.recognitionRequest.append(buffer)
            })

            audioEngine.prepare()

                try audioEngine.start()
       }
    } catch {

    } 
    }
}

// Function called when I release the record button
func EndRecording() {
    endRecording()
    print("Stop recording")
}

func endRecording() {
    audioEngine.stop()
    recognitionRequest.endAudio()
    audioEngine.inputNode?.removeTap(onBus: 0)
}

func playSound(sound: String) {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: sound, withExtension: "wav") {
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            guard let player = audioPlayer else { return }
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.play()
            print("tutu")
        } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

func compareWordwithVoice() {

    let StringToLearn = setWordToLearn()
    print("StringToLearn : \(StringToLearn)")
    if let StringRecordedFull = instructionLabel.text{
        let StringRecorded = (StringRecordedFull as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()
    print("StringRecorded : \(StringRecorded)")
        if StringRecorded == "appuyezsurleboutonendessousetprenoncezl’expression" {
            print("not yet")
        } else {
            if StringToLearn == StringRecorded {

        playSound(sound: "success")
        print("success")
        // update UI
    } else {
        playSound(sound: "oops")
        print("oops")
        // update UI
    }
        }

    }
}

 func setWordToLearn() -> String {
    if let wordToLearnFull = expr?.expression {
        print(wordToLearnFull)
        var wordToLearn = (wordToLearnFull as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "").lowercased()
        wordToLearn = (wordToLearn as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
        wordToLearn = (wordToLearn as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "!", with: "")
        wordToLearn = (wordToLearn as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "?", with: "")
        wordToLearn = (wordToLearn as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: ",", with: "")
        wordToLearn = (wordToLearn as NSString).replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "")
        print(wordToLearn)
        return wordToLearn
    }
    print("no wordToLearn")
    return ""

}
```

The problem is that the playSound works perfectly when it is in the viewDidLoad but doesn't work when it is called by the compareThing() function but it display "tutu" on both cases so it performs the playSound function every time.

Can the problem be if AVAudioPlayer and AVAudioEngine cannot work at the same time ?

Thx

Comment: Yes I didn't put the code where I use it. It's in another function.

Comment: As far as I see you call play sound in both `if` and `else`..it's normal that you have that function called in both statements

Comment: Ok I see. I edit the post and put the whole code. Ty

Comment: Anyone can help me to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ive experienced the same thing with my code and from searching online it seems like there is an unspoken bug "when using AvAudioPlayer and Engine separately"

I got the information from the following link. I did not find anything else online that states why this bug happens though.
https://swiftios8dev.wordpress.com/2015/03/05/sound-effects-using-avaudioengine/

The suggestion was to use AVAudioEngine for everything.

Comment: Oh that interesting. Thank you for that tips.

Answer (score 0):

I think "compareThings" always plays "oops" sound and this sound is not good (too quiet or broken).

Please try to play "oops" sound from "viewDidLoad" func to make sure sound is okay.
If it is okay (I don't think so) - set breakpoint in "playSound" func to see what is going on (sound name, does it exists etc).

Comment: The oops sound works perfectly in viewDidLoad() and with the breackpoint, every thing looks fine (url, sounds name)

Comment: did you find something ?

Comment: I see that you you added more source code. But I don't see where you are calling "compareThings" function and where "thing1" and "thing1" were declared. So I cannot copy-paste your code and see what happens.